# Modify Running kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have created a yaml file for kubernetes cluster 
which holds two docker images(2 micro services). created a cluster from it . 
`kubectl create -f pod.yaml`
Cluster is running now.

I wish to add another one new docker image(new micro services to get delpoyed) or remove an existing one docker image from that cluster.

Is it possible in the same cluster?

Comment: Just create a new deployment, you don't have to modify the existing cluster

Comment: new deployment with new cluster ?

Comment: Maybe show your .yaml file(s)

Answer (score 1):

I would hold from going into the part where you said `which holds two docker images(2 microservices).` which might be a separate discussion and is more subjective.

You can add another container spec to your YAML and apply it:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container1
//.. more stuff
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container2
//.. more stuff
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container3
```

But additionally define `deploymentStrategy` to be `RollingUpdateDeployment` so that not all pods are taken down at the same time and they are replaced in a controlled manner without affecting end-user traffic.

Of course if your two versions of the application (one with 2 containers and one with 3) are not compatible with rest of the system then this won't solve your problem.

In which case - it is best to stand up another deployment for new version of application and divert traffic using DNS/routing mechanisms to new version of application.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally considered best practice that a pod contains only a single container/service. If that is the case, you can simply create another *deployment* configuration file to add a new service and apply it using kubectl.

If you wish to delete a deployments, you can use the `kubectl delete deployment` command.